# VB.NET Calling class functions after declared as an Object

Tags: vb.net, class, generics, object

I want to see if there is a way to do this... I'm Using vs2010 with the WP7 SDK. (VB.NET)

I am declaring this in the global scope.

`public objGame as object`

then say i have classes: `Game1` and `Game2`

for the sake of the example we'll just say both classes have an `Update()` function

I want to set `objGame = Game1`    (or Game2)

and then be able to call `objGame.Update()`

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an interface IGame with method Update(). Inherit both of Game1 and Game2 from it.

```
IGame objGame= Game1() [or Game2]

objGame.Update()
```

Here's wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) on Polymorphism in OOP.

Comment: +1 for right information and suggestion..but op is somewhat regarding the extracting the reference type of assigned class object...

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the type of class object and then call the update method after casting it the particular class.

code snippet in C#, may be you will understand what to do. Here `object` in the Shared class and set the object to your class either Game1 or Game2. then access then use little reflection to work with object are run time.

```
public static class GameCommon
    {
        public static object currentGame;
    }
```

/// Use .GetType()

```
GameCommon.currentGame = new Game1();

            if (GameCommon.currentGame != null)
            {
                Type type = GameCommon.currentGame.GetType();
                if (type.Name == "Game1")
                {
                    ((Game1)GameCommon.currentGame).Update();    
                }
                else if (type.Name == "Game2")
                {
                    ((Game2)GameCommon.currentGame).Update();    
                }
            }`
```

The another best approach it `Interface` polymorphism and IMHO it is the correct way to implement..

Check this:

```
public static class GameCommon
    {
        public static IGame currentGame;
    }

    public interface IGame
    {
        void Update();
    }
    public class Game1 : IGame
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running:Game1 Updated");
        }
    }

    public class Game2 : IGame
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running:Game2 Updated");
        }
    }`
```

Call it as:

```
GameCommon.currentGame = new Game1();

            if (GameCommon.currentGame != null)
            {
                GameCommon.currentGame.Update();
            }

            GameCommon.currentGame = new Game2();
            GameCommon.currentGame.Update();
            Console.ReadKey();`
```

Hope this help you..

Answer (score -1):

First declare your public object as either Game1 or Game2

```
Public objGame As New Game1
```

Then whatever you do with the object is actually representing either Game1 or Game2

```
objGame.Update()
```